# C LANG Using array to read in colums as well as rows

Tags: c, arrays

I have a project for school where I need to read in the values from a large text file and find the max and min number. This code works for a small text file where the numbers are like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My question is how would I modify it so it would read in and find the max and min for a file that contained the numbers like so:

```
123
456
789
12345
1245676
```

EDIT: The numbers just post in a line. but basically I want my array to read in both columns and rows. Thanks

```
//inputting numbers from a text file, finding max and min in array and displaying them//
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   //Declare variables//
    int size_of_array = 10;
    int x[10] = {0};
    int i;
    int max;
    int min;

    FILE *input_fptr;

    //open file for reading//
    input_fptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(input_fptr != NULL)
    {
        //Read in file contents//
        for(i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
        {
            fscanf(input_fptr,"%d", & x[i]);
        }
        fclose(input_fptr);
        //min and max calculations//
        max = x[0];
        min = x[0];
        for( i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
        {
            if(x[i] > max)
            {
            max = x[i];
            }

            if(x[i] < min)
            {
            min = x[i];
            }
        }

    }
    //Print results//
     printf("Largest element in array is : %d\n", max);
     printf("Smallest element in array is : %d\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work for the second list of numbers? What happens if you put the second list of numbers in input.txt and execute your program? Does it fail? Does it output anything? Also note that I see 5 numbers, but your `size_of_array` is 10, dunno, maybe there are 5 numbers in the file not 10.

Comment: This was old code that I tried to use for this project.. inputting the array size is impractical because there is a huge ammount of numbers, I need to input all these numbers into an array (or 2, 1 for collums and 1 for rows) and then find the max, min, average, sum and then change certain numbers too 255 and certain numbers to 0

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an array to store the numbers. Just read one number at a time, comparing against the current max and min numbers.

In pseudo-ish code something like

```
int current_min = INT_MAX;
int current_max = INT_MIN;

while (read_one_number(&number))
{
    if (number < current_min)
        current_min = number;

    if (number > current_max)
        current_max = number;
}
```

And `fscanf(input_fptr, "%d", ...)` will read any *space-delimited* decimal integer. If the "space" is a newline, tab or normal space doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok I didnt explain myself properly its my first time posting on a fourm, I have a project where I am given a PGM file and I need to input all the numbers into an array (or 2 arrays one for colums and 1 for rows) and then change all pixel values of 110 to 0 and all other pixel values to 255... I am just struggling on how to read in all of these values into an array

Comment: @Quinny PGM files usually contains a header that contains the dimensions of the image. You need to read and parse that, then use dynamic allocation to create a matrix of suitable dimensions. Then you can use a loop within a loop to read each row and each column of that row into the matrix you just created.

Comment: @Quinny Though for the problem description you have, you could just read the numbers one by one from the input file, and write the modified values to the output file. There's no need to store the entire image in the program, only the last read value.